# How do you add Intern to a Dojo project?

Tags: javascript, dojo, intern

The tutorial on the Intern site starts off by acquiring intern using npm, but I downloaded the latest release of Intern source code.  (I'm not using npm) and my app folder structure is like this

```
|myapp
    |app
    |tests
       |unit
       |functional
    main.js
|third-party
    |dojo-release-1.10.6
    |intern-3.4.2
index.html
```

Now in my index.html I added the following in my packages config

```
            packages: [
                { name: 'dojo', location: 'third_party/dojo-release-1.10.6-src/dojo' },
                { name: 'intern', location: 'third_party/intern-3.4.2' },
            ],
```

After this, where do I place the intern.js?

Comment: place it inside `intern/intern.js` then import it like `require("intern/intern.js")` ...

Answer (score 0):

Aside from using npm, the basic process of using Intern will be the same as that outlined in the tutorial. Write your unit tests, then use one of Intern's three test runners (`intern-client`, `intern-runner`, or `client.html`) to actually run the tests.

You don't need to include Intern in your application packages list. Instead, you'll include your app packages in the [`loaderOptions`](https://theintern.github.io/intern/#option-loader) object in your Intern test config.

How your tests interact with your application depends on what kinds of tests you're writing. For unit tests, your unit test suites will load pieces of your application and then run tests on them. For functional tests, your tests (through Intern) will tell a browser to load a test page running your application, and then tell the browser to take various actions.

```
// unit test
define([ 'intern!object', 'myApp/myModule' ], function (registerSuite, mod) {
    registerSuite({
        name: 'myApp/myModule',

        '#someFunction': function () {
            var value = mod.someFunction(...);
            // make assertion about value
        }
    });
});

// functional test
define([ 'intern!object' ], function (registerSuite) {
    registerSuite({
        name: 'myApp/myModule',

        '#someFunction': function () {
            return this.remote.get('myTestPage.html')
                .findById('someButton')
                .click()
                // make assertions about state of elements on the page
        }
    });
});
```

Intern itself is a Dojo project, and uses its own custom version of Dojo to load modules by default. That may be sufficient for unit tests. If it's not, you you'll want to set [`loaders`](https://theintern.github.io/intern/#option-useLoader) in your test config to point to your own Dojo's `dojo.js` (the path to your loader should be relative to Intern's `dojo/loader.js`).